# Determine $y$ explicitly as a function of $x:$ $\ln(1+y)-\ln(y)=\ln(x^3+1)-2 \ln(x-1)$

Tags: logarithms, systems-of-equations

I have taken the exp on both sides to give;

$$e^{\ln(1+y)}-e^{\ln y}=e^{\ln(x^3+1)}-e^{2\ln(x-1)}$$
$$1+y-y=x^3+1-(x-1)^2$$

Then simplified the LHS and factored the RHS to give;

$$y=(x-1)(x^2-2)$$

Is this correct, or have i gone too far down the rabbit hole?

Comment: Use $\ln(x)-\ln(y)=\ln(\frac{x}{y}), \ln(x^y)=y\ln(x)$, raise both sides to the power of $e$ and simplify.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the exponent is not linear:
$$a+b=c+d$$
Means:
$$\exp(a+b)=\exp(c+d) $$
$$\exp(a) \exp(b) =\exp(c) \exp(d) $$

My hint to you is to first combine the logarithms using the identities:
$$ \log(a)+\log(b) = \log(ab)$$
$$ \log(a)-\log(b) = \log(\frac{a}{b})$$
$$c \log(a) = \log(a^c) $$

If you use these, you can simplify the terms to two logs on each side and the apply the exponentiation. 
You will get something like:
$$\ln\left(\frac{1+y}{y}\right)= \ln\left(\frac{x^3+1}{(x-1)^2}\right)$$
$$\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{y}\right)= \ln\left(\frac{x^3+1}{(x-1)^2}\right)$$
So:
$$1+\frac{1}{y} =\frac{x^3+1}{(x-1)^2}$$

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but would i still check that the equation balances on both sides by substituting a value in? or does that not apply to explicity equations?

Comment: @RocketKangaroo : You are welcome to check and confirm by substituting in values The equations still satisfy. (Be careful regarding the domains of $x$ and $y$ as $\ln$ is defined on $(0,\infty)$.